# Replacing of Pandas DataFrame values on columns and multi-indices

Tags: python, statistics, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe with hierarchical index. It is entirely composed of integers (and potentially NaNs). For each level in the index, and for some of the columns, I have a dictionary that maps every integer to a different string, and I want to present the dataframe with the strings and not the columns. I'm testing code as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mappings = {'ace': {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e'},
            'algo': {0:'x', 1:'y', 2:'z', 3:'w', 4:'v'},
            'lucky': {0:'str0', 1:'str1', 2:'str2', 3:'str3', 4:'str4'}}
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randint(0, 5, (100, 5)), 
                   columns=('ace', 'spade', 'lucky', 'algo', 'boo') )
_a = df.set_index(['ace', 'algo'])
_b = df.groupby(['ace', 'algo']).size()
groups_small = _b[_b <= _b.quantile(0.7)].index
df_out = _a.drop(groups_small)
```

So for example, if `df_out` is:

```
          spade  lucky  boo
ace algo
0   1         3      0    0
    4         0      0    1
1   4         0      4    3
3   3         1      4    4
    3         2      1    1
2   0         0      3    1
0   4         2      2    1
    1         0      4    2
    1         3      3    3
```

I want it to be transformed into:

```
          spade  lucky  boo
ace algo
a   y         3   str0    0
    v         0   str0    1
b   v         0   str4    3
d   w         1   str4    4
    w         2   str1    1
c   x         0   str3    1
a   v         2   str2    1
    y         0   str4    2
    y         3   str3    3
```

By means of `mappings`. Which operations do I have to perform?

Comment: Why not just perform the mappings prior to groupby? e.g. `df.algo = df.algo.map(mappings['algo'])` etc..

Comment: Thanks @EdChum! That works, but the real table will be several thousand rows long, and the operation will happen several times per second, so that's why I want to show the strings only in the condensed output.

Comment: I still think it is better to have your data in the form you want prior to the grouping if this is ultimately what you want anyway. You can update the `lucky` column in the `df_out` but I don't think you can modify the index in the way you want without it being an expensive operation. If you retained the columns as indexing, e.g. `_a = df.set_index(['ace', 'algo'], drop=False)` then you could still perform the mapping on the final `df_out` and then switch the index using `set_index` again.

Comment: You again on the spot @EdChum! So the solution after doing `set_index` with `drop=False` makes me perform the following loop: `for field, mapping in mappings.iteritems(): df_out[field] = df_out[field].map(mapping)`. That gets the job done, but maybe there is already a function that does this...

Comment: I think calling `map` is the fastest method as this will vectorize the operation without performing an expensive loop iteration. Personally I would create the DataFrame with the correct data in the first place rather than using integer values which then need to be converted into strings, several thousand rows is not a lot so it should be quick to perform the mapping prior to grouping

Comment: `map` *does* iterate. You don't see it, but if you dig in you'll eventually get to a `list` comprehension or a `for` loop.

Comment: @PhillipCloud wasn't aware of that I knew that `apply` did iterate but thought `map` didn't

Comment: @EdChum I was half wrong. I took a look at the `Series.map()` method. It uses a Cython for loop, so it's faster than looping in pure Python, but it still has to accept an arbitrary callable, which will add some overhead.